# How to write scientific notation in perl?

Tags: perl, scientific-notation

I have been working on a program for a while, and the next goal I have to say basically

> "In column [27] if the value is more than `10^-8` delete the file"

How does one write `10^-8` in a program?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @traitarray;
my $traitarray;
my $input ;
my %traithash ;
my $t_out ;
my $TRAIT;
my $SNPS;

open ($input, "gwas_catalog_v1.0-downloaded_2015-07-31.tsv") || die () ;

while(<$input>) {
    @traitarray = split (/\t/);
    $TRAIT = $traitarray[7];
    $SNPS = $traitarray[21];

    if (!exists $traithash {$TRAIT}) {
            $TRAIT =~ tr/ /_/ ;
            $TRAIT =~ tr/:/-/ ;
            $TRAIT =~ tr/\//-/ ;
            $TRAIT =~ tr/*/-/ ;
            open ($t_out, ">outputFiles/".$TRAIT.".txt");
            print $t_out "$SNPS\n";
            $traithash {$TRAIT} = 1 ;
            push (@traitarray, $TRAIT) ;
    }
    else {
        print $t_out "$SNPS\n";
    }
}

foreach ($traitarray) {
    close "$TRAIT.txt";
}
```

Column [27] has about 30,000 lines in the format of "6E-12" " "12E-9"  ect...

Comment: What is column 27? Example: `perl -E 'say 1e-8*1e8'`

Comment: See [`perlnumber`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html) for more information..

Comment: You should post the code

Comment: Incidentally, `tr` can do more than one character at a time: `$TRAIT =~ tr{ :/*}{_\-\--};`

Comment: `$traitarray` never has any contents, and should be removed. The one place you do actually use it should be changed to `foreach my $TRAIT (@traitarray){ close "TRAIT.txt"; }`, You should either add `use autodie;` next to `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, or check the return values of `open` and `close`. I encourage you to read the book [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/), which the publisher has made free to read online in several formats [including html](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/).

Answer (score 5):

Just use `1e-8`

`e` is the common notation for exponents.

Example: `5.5e100` is (5.5 * 10^100)

More Info: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), [perlnumber](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html) (thanks to Håkon Hægland)

Answer (score 2):

[Anachor already correctly pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811103/1331451) out that Perl understands the exponential notation. But there is more to it.

Lucky for you, your data looks exactly like that exponential notation. Because Perl does not distinguish between numbers and strings, you can use a numerical operator on that value. So you can quite literally say this:

```
my $small_number = "6E-12";
if ($small_number > 8e-10) {
  say "Over threshhold, I should delete this...";
}
```

Of course if there is something else in your column 27 than a number, that will give a warning (because you have `use warnings`, right?).